# How to set require path in Laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have an controller in default path of Laravel project

```
/app/Http/Controllers/PaymentController.php
```

In the same path there is an directory:

```
/app/Http/Controllers/merchant/
```

with files inside.

I tried to include one file from this directory in controller like:

```
require_once './merchant/private/filter/filter.php';
```

But it does not work. What do I do wrong, or Laravel does not allow to do this?

I get this error:

> main(): Failed opening required './merchant/private/filter/filter.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')

Comment: That `require` statements has no relation to "merchant". Please don't just copy random text code from internet and expect it to work. It usually helps, if you learn the programming language, before starting to use a framework.

Comment: Sorry I made mistake when posted, look again

Comment: How does "doesn't work" look like? Have you enabled error reporting? Was there a reason why you used relative path instead of absolute? Why are you putting any of it inside folder called "controllers"?

Comment: I get this error: `main(): Failed opening required './merchant/private/filter/filter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')`

Comment: It means that there is no such file or it is not readable.

Comment: It has root/root permission and rwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use `require_*`. Laravel uses autoloading from composer. Therefore your class must have a proper namespace definition like

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controller\Merchant\Private\Filter;
   ```

   which you use via a `use` statement

   ```
   use App\Http\Controller\Merchant\Private\Filter\Filter;
   ```
2. Classes should be UpperCamelCase -> `Filter.php` instead of `filter.php`